# UITextViewDelegate inside a class func

Tags: ios, swift3, uikit

I am using swift 3 and I have a class as the following:

```
class Assistor : NSObject , UITextViewDelegate {


private override init() {

}

class func RegisterTextView(uiview:UIView) {

    if let RegisteredView = uiview as? UITextView {
        RegisteredView.delegate = self as! UITextViewDelegate
    }
}


func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("Begin")
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    print("End")
}
}
```

From a normal uiviewcontroller I want to call the Assistor function like this in the viewDidLoad:

```
class InqueryDetailsViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var AnswerTextView:UITextView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

Assistor.RegisterTextView(uiview: AnswerTextView)
}
}
```

As it is clearly, I want to trigger textViewDidBeginEditing from the assistor not from the uiviewcontroller. how to do that?

Comment: where is your code declaring and initializing your `Assistor`? and your RegisterTextView must be a instance func

Comment: I edited the question so you can see the calling uiviewcontroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `Assistor` must be declared as object, if you want only one you can make it as singleton, you need to change the init to public, and change the registerTextView as instance method

**try with this**

```
class Assistor : NSObject , UITextViewDelegate {

    //Singleton
     static let sharedInstance: Assistor = Assistor()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func registerTextView(uiview:UIView) {
        if let RegisteredView = uiview as? UITextView {
            RegisteredView.delegate = self as! UITextViewDelegate
        }
    }


    func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("Begin")
    }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
        print("End")
    }
}
```

**Using it**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

    var assistor : Assistor = Assistor()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.assistor.registerTextView(uiview: self.textView)
        //using as singleton
        //Assistor.sharedInstance.registerTextView(uiview: self.textView)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: the part of using singleton worked as a charm. Thanks bro.

Comment: from my reading I knew that using singleton is not recommended. Is this applies to the above scenario?

Comment: from my reading I knew that using singleton is not recommended. Is this applies to the above scenario?

Comment: I know is not recommended, is better declare as property, but as singleton also work @FamousMaxy

Comment: why it is not recommended?

Comment: @FamousMaxy Now you are making me doubt about this, maybe is ok as singleton, in fact I don't see any problem